# perfect square wave cannot be played back

Tags: audio, wave

If I produce a square-wave by creating a sine wave first and then doing,
if x >= 0 return 1, else return -1
this produces a "perfect" square wave(python code).
Like this the audio signal cannot even be played back.

But if I slightly randomize the signal
if x >= 0 return rand(0.9999,1), else return rand(-0.9999,-1)
it works.

Even though I'm confronted with this in the context of programming 
I assume that people from this forum will know the answer.

Comment: The domain of PCM-encoded audio does not go all the way from -1 to 1 inclusive.

Comment: Nobody has ever produced a perfect square wave BTW.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams you're right! Simply setting the range excluding 1/-1 fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @oax1: What do you mean by "the audio signal cannot even be played back"?

Comment: No audio software I tried was able to play the audio file  back. None of them started the playback. I guess it is because including -1,1 is invalid.